# The ability to go back to the full sites list

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I find myself swiping to the left, clicking the show all sites buttons and then scrolling back to where I was prior to selecting a question. An easy way to go back to where you were in the sites list would be greatly appreciated.

[image: List of sites]

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add the details asked by the users in comments. No need to post a separate answer for that.

Comment: I understand that, but I didn’t see the ability to include an image on the mobile app

Comment: I still don’t understand, what are you trying to do. Could you be a bit more clarifying?